# Fllutter: Erorr : '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I find this error  and I need help resolving this error:

> error:    '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

URL return JSON:

> {**"userId": 1**,"id": **1**,"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit","body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}**

This code:  API

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../model/user_model.dart';

String appUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

class AppRepostry {
  Future<List<UserModel>> getApp() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(appUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List resuilt = jsonDecode(response.body);

      return resuilt.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}


model:
class UserModel {
  int? userId;
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? body;

  UserModel({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['userId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

UI:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<AppsBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => AppsBloc(AppRepostry()),
          )
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("key app top api"),
          ),
          body: BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => AppsBloc(
              AppRepostry(),
            )..add(LoadAppEvent()),
            child: BlocBuilder<AppsBloc, UsreState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is LoadingAppState) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (state is LoadedAppState) {
                  List<UserModel> usermodel = state.apps;
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: usermodel.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
                          child: Card(
                            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text('${usermodel[index].title}'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
                if (state is ErorrAppState) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("No Data ERORR"),
                  );
                }
                return Container();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering, '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List', is due to the fact that the response from the API is a JSON object, but you are treating it as if it were a list in your getApp method.

The API response looks like this:

json:

```
{"userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}
```

It's a JSON object ({}), not a JSON array ([]). So, you should decode it as a Map<String, dynamic> instead of a List.

Here's the corrected getApp method:

```
class AppRepostry {
  Future<List<UserModel>> getApp() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(appUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> result = jsonDecode(response.body);

      // Since the API returns a single object, we create a List with one element.
      return [UserModel.fromJson(result)];
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you are treating the response as a single item list, and you are parsing the JSON object into a UserModel instance. In your LoadedAppState block, you can access the data like this:

```
List<UserModel> usermodel = state.apps;
UserModel userModel = usermodel[0]; // Since it's a single item list
print(userModel.title); // Accessing the title property
```

This should resolve the error you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` response is a object not a list.

object:

```json
{
 ...
 ...
}
```

list:

```
{
   [
      ...
   ]
}
```

so in your case change return value on `AppRepostry`

example:

```dart
class AppRepostry {

  /// list ~
  Future<List<PostsEntity>> getPosts() async {
    const endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(endpoint));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return result.map((e) => PostsEntity.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }

  /// object
  Future<PostsEntity> getPost(int id) async {
    final endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/$id';
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(endpoint));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Decode the response body
      var decodedData = json.decode(response.body);
      return PostsEntity.fromJson(decodedData);
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the data coming from json is of type List.

and do not forget List not equals List<string,dynamic>. So List<"1",User> not equals List.

You must create the model class in accordance with the incoming j data type.

```
if json came just like this : {...} => Map. So Object. So User
if json came just like this : [{...},{...}] => List. So Object List. So User List
```

Please review my article on medium. If there's still something you don't understand, let me know. If I see your message, I will help you again.

Here is my medium blog:
https://medium.com/@mkiziltay/how-to-generate-model-class-with-dart-from-json-list-555c30289831

If you read and understand my article above, it will be very useful for you. I explained how you can create model classes while getting answers from objects and object lists.